# Google app engine Java - import CSV to datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I was looking into uploading a CSV to blobstore on this site, and only found solutions for python code, but I need it for a java application.

Here is where I am right now:

Step 1 : I upload CSV to BlobStore the code is

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ServletBulkUpAgent extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
        BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("data");

        if (blobKey == null) {
            resp.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect("/upload-success?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());
        }


    }
}
```

Step 2 : just read the CSV file using openCSV.jar file and print the value.
The code for this is (this below cod transfer from above code after successfull upload).

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SuccessfulUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Enter Successful Upload");

        String blobKey = req.getParameter("blob-key");


        BlobstoreInputStream is = new BlobstoreInputStream(new BlobKey(blobKey));

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        List<String[]> rows = csvReader.readAll();

        System.out.println(rows);

    }

}
```

But its throws the following error:

> Problem accessing /_ah/upload/ag1oaWxmZWRlc2tkZW1vciILEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YgICAgICAkAgM. Reason:
>   Java heap space

Since I'm looking for a java solution, pointing me back to a Python workaround won't really do the trick here.

Comment: How big is your CSV file?

Comment: my CSV file is 46 bytes